# :1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to stackoverflow
I'm getting this error

```
gcc -Wall -o "merge" "merge.c" (in directory: /home/jenson/Documents)  
Compilation failed.  
merge.c: In function ‘part’: 
merge.c:7:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token  
 {  
 ^  
merge.c:18:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token  
 {  
 ^  
merge.c:37:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token  
 {  
 ^  
merge.c:3:6: error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition  
void part(int a[], int n)  
     ^  
merge.c:54:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input  
 }  
 ^
```

the code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void part(int a[], int n)
void merge(int a[],int n);
void sort(int[],int[],int n);
void main()
{
    int arr[10],i,n;
    printf("enter the 10 numbers :\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    n=10;
    part(arr,n);
}
void sort(int a[],int b[],int n)
{
int i=0,j=0,t=0,c[10];
    while(i<n&&j<n)
    {
        if(a[i]>b[j])
        {
            c[t]=b[j];
            j++;
            t++
        }
        else
        {
            c[t]=a[i];
            i++;
            t++;
        }
    }
}
void part(int f[],int n)
{
    int f[10],g[10];
    if(n>=1)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<floor(n/2);i++)
        {
            f[i]=d[i];
        }
        part(f,floor(n/2));
        for(i=floor(n/2);i<n;i++)
        {
            g[i]=d[i];
        }
        part(f,feil(n/2));
    }
    sort(f,g,n);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

semi-colon missing in the prototype declaration

```
void part(int a[], int n)
                         ^
```

Another one missing in `sort()` function, inside `if`

```
t++
   ^
```

Comment: Also part() has 2 declarations for 'f' (one is a parameter), 0 declarations for 'd' (which is used, but not declared), and I believe 'feil' is supposed to be 'ceil' (for ceiling as opposed to floor).  It may also be necessary to `#include <math.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code , after recompiling it many times , should be like this i think i did helped you .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
void part(int a[], int n);
void merge(int a[],int n);
void sort(int[],int[],int n);
void main()
{
    int arr[10],i,n;
    printf("enter the 10 numbers :\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    n=10;
    part(arr,n);
}
void sort(int a[],int b[],int n)
{
int i=0,j=0,t=0,c[10];
    while(i<n&&j<n)
    {
        if(a[i]>b[j])
        {
            c[t]=b[j];
            j++;
            t++;
        }
        else;
        {
            c[t]=a[i];
            i++;
            t++;
        }
    }
}
void part(int f[] ,int n)
{
    int a[10],g[10],d[10];
    if(n>=1)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<(floor(n/2));i++)
        {
            f[i]=d[i];
        }
        part(f,floor(n/2));
        for(i=floor(n/2);i<n;i++)
        {
            g[i]=d[i];
        }
        part(f,ceil(n/2));
    }
    sort(f,g,n);
}
```